# how to load external javascript inside partial view dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html, partial

I'm using jquery's .html() function to inject a html file into a partial div of the main page of my application. In the injected partial html page, there is a javascript reference such as script(src='../../javascripts/partialFunctions.js'). 
The jquery function and the main page are like:

```
$('.partialDiv').html(htmlResult);

<div>main page</div>
<div class='partialDiv'></div>
<input type='button'>button</input>
```

When the user click a specific button on the main application page, the jquery function will got called and the html file will got injected to the main page.

The problem is every time a new htm file got injected, the browser will load the script file. So there will be many duplicated javascript functions after the user clicked the button several times.

How can I do this dynamically and avoid the duplication of javascript functions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not include the script in the main page to begin with?

Comment: I want to load different html pages and javascript files to the partialDiv when user click different buttons. So I don't want to load all the js files when the main page is loaded.

Comment: "Wanting to" doesn't really explain the technical reasoning. If it's about data, then include the data in the partial page and have the main script look for it on load.

Comment: Since there are many js functions for each different partial html page, I think it will be slow to load all the functions at once.

Comment: Ummmm...the average JPG is bigger than most JS files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the script tags and references from the `htmlResult` page.
Then use `$.getScript('myscript.js')` to import the necessary JavaScript files.
More info on [getScript() here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)

So to load in the script and make sure it only loads in once:

```
var window.foo = false; //Outside the document.ready

$('.partialDiv').html(htmlResult);
if(window.foo == false){
    $.getScript("js/myScript.js", function(data, textStatus, jqxhr){
        console.log('Script loaded');
        window.foo = true;
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But the $.getScript() will still load the js file agin even if the js file is already loaded. Is there anyway I can prevent this?

Comment: It turns out the problem is caused by my socket.on() function. I defined the socket.on() function in the javascript file, so every time the file is loaded, it will add a new event handler to the socket.

Comment: Well if you still need to load the file in once, you could declare a boolean. `False` before load, and once its loaded change it to `true`, so it doesn't get loaded. `if(bool == false){ $.getScript('script.js'); bool = true;}`

Answer (score 0):

I just did a quick test, it looks like script tags are stripped out anyways when you call `.html()`. So you should be able to simply do:

```
var html = "<html><script></script></html>",
    cleanedHtml = $(html).html();
myEl.html(cleanedHtml);
```